# How to change value of a cell (that already has a value) based on the value on another cell?

Tags: excel

So in cell A6 I enter a value (like 6.5). I've linked cell D6 to a check box.

How can I make it so that when I check the checkbox and thus change the value of D6 to TRUE, it changes the value of A6 to "Done"?

Comment: With vba.  SO is not a code for me site.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change A6 to a formula to do this:

```
=If(D6="True", "Done", 6.5)
```

You can't have a value like 6.5 in the cell AND have it's value change via a formula. If you absolutely must have a cell where you can type a value like `6.5` (say B6) then in A6 you can do:

```
=If(D6="True", "Dont", B6)
```

If that still isn't a good enough compromise, then you will have to resort to VBA, wherein the Sheet's code you would have something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6")) Is Nothing Then
        If Sheet1.Range("D6").Value = "True" Then
            Sheet1.Range("A6").Value = "Done"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This will detect a change in `D6` and if that change results in a value of `True` then it will update `A6` to `"Done"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quick and dirty macro attached to your checkbox. But it really depends on what functionality you want:

```
Sub changetoDone()

Range("A6").Value = "Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First run this to make a checkbox:

```
Sub MakeCheckbox()
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(358.5, 93, 41.25, 33).Select
    Selection.Text = "Click Me"
End Sub
```

and then assign this macro to it:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(1).Value = 1 Then
        Range("D6").Value = True
        Range("A6").Value = "Done"
    Else
        Range("D6").Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```